# How do I represent in code a schema.org Thing marked up as text?

Tags: schema.org

*Note that this question is at the border of StackOverflow and ProWebmasters, so please forgive me if you think that it belongs to SO; but I'm afraid that it would be closed over there as "not a programming question".* Anyway:

---

I'm implementing a PHP library to parse schema.org structured data and represent them using objects that match schema.org types: `Product`, `Offer`, etc.

I've so far identified 3 ways properties are used:

- **The property has a Thing type, and is marked up as such**

  Example: [Product](https://schema.org/Product).[offers](https://schema.org/offers)

  This is self-explanatory, and can be translated in code as a `$offers` property containing a list of `Offer` objects:

  ```
  "@type": "Product",
  "offers": {
      "@type": "Offer",
      "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
      "price": "55.00",
      "priceCurrency": "USD"
    },
  ```

  This maps straight to code that could look like:

  ```php
  class Product {
      /** @var Offer[] */
      public $offers;
  }
  ```

  ---
- **The property has a [Text](https://schema.org/Text) type, and is marked up using a simple string**

  Example: [Product](https://schema.org/Product).[color](https://schema.org/color)

  This is self-explanatory as well: `Text` is a [DataType](https://schema.org/DataType). It can be mapped in code to a native data type such as `string`:

  ```
  "@type": "Product",
  "color": "red",
  ```

  ```php
  class Product {
      /** @var string */
      public $color;
  }
  ```

  The same goes with properties of type `Number`, `Date`, etc. These are all `DataType`s that could map to a native type in code, and that make sense to mark up as a simple string.

  ---
- **The property has a Thing type, but the docs suggest to use it as a text property** (!)

  Example: [ExerciseAction](https://schema.org/ExerciseAction).[distance](https://schema.org/distance)

  [Distance](https://schema.org/Distance) is *not* a `DataType`, **it's an object that extends from `Thing`** and whose only properties are those inherited from `Thing`:

  `Thing` > `Intangible` > `Quantity` > `Distance`

  Still, **the doc does not say to mark it up as an object with properties, but as a simple text string**. Example straight from [ExerciseAction](https://schema.org/ExerciseAction):

  ```
  "@type": "ExerciseAction",
  ...
  "distance": "100 miles",
  ```

I'm struggling with this last one, which seems to be a mix of a `Thing` and a `DataType`.

### Question 1

**How am I supposed to represent a `Distance` in code, when it's represented as text in the markup?**

As a `Distance` is a `Thing`, it would feel wrong to me to represent it as a `string` in code; I'd rather convert this text value to a `Distance` object. But then, **where should the textual value go?** In the [name](https://schema.org/name) property for example?

Is handling of these `Quantity` values documented anywhere? I found an [issue on the schemaorg repo](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/551) that seems to support the feeling that there's an ambiguity here.

### Question 2

**Is a text string the only correct usage for a `Distance` property**, or can we encounter a `Distance` as an object, such as the following?

```
"@type": "ExerciseAction",
"distance": {
    "@type": "Distance",
    "name": ...
}
```

Note that Google's [structured data testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) does not seem to care and accepts both. It does not seem to apply any conversion either, i.e. it outputs a textual `distance` as is, without converting it to a `@type Distance`.

---

I've browsed for other implementations of schema.org parsers to get inspiration (and answers) from, in any language, but didn't find anything close to what I'm trying to achieve here.

Comment: Just in case you missed it: properties can also have a `URL` value. While this is also a `DataType`, you can’t treat it as regular string, because the URLs might be relative references.

Comment: Can *all* properties have a URL value? Why do some of them explicitly have URL in their type list, and others do not? Could you please point me to the relevant docs? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, all properties can have a URL value (see [Conformance](https://schema.org/docs/datamodel.html#conformance)). It’s explicitly listed for those properties for which it’s common/useful/making sense to provide URLs.

Answer (score 1):

The property distance can be extended with type **[Distance](https://schema.org/Distance)**. In turn, this type has the property identifier that can be extended using the type **[PropertyValue](https://schema.org/PropertyValue)**. This type has the following properties that may be useful to you:

- value
- unitText
- unitCode

All of the above creates data type embedding. 
So my suggestion is how to present your 100 miles as a distance with the specified unit length:

```
    {
  "@context":"https://schema.org",
  "@type":"ExerciseAction",
  "agent":{
    "@type":"Person",
    "name":"John"
  },
  "exerciseType":"Running",
  "distance": {
    "@type":"Distance",
    "identifier":{
      "@type":"PropertyValue",
      "value":"100",
      "unitCode":"SMI",
      "sameAs":"http://www.unece.org/fileadmin/DAM/cefact/recommendations/bkup_htm/add2e.htm"
    }
  },
  "participant": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "Steve"
  }
}
```

Note that the property sameAs has value as the link of *Units of Measure: Code elements listed by name*.

Comment: I don’t think it makes sense to use `identifier` and `sameAs` like that. a) "100 miles" is not the identifier of the `Distance` item. b) The `sameAs` for the `PropertyValue` item would have to be a URI that represents this specific property value (i.e., 100 miles, and probably exactly these specific 100 miles, not just any).